# Get the current image source of a picture element

Tags: javascript, responsive-images, srcset

An [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) has a `currentSrc` property so we can get the current source of an `img` element. Useful when defining multiple possible sources with `srcset`.

There seems to be no equivalent for an [HTMLPictureElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLPictureElement).

Is there another way we can find the current source of a `picture` element with Javascript?

Comment: picture is only a container element to provide different sources for an image element inside the picture container - so I would assume that `currentSrc` of the `img` element works the same way here …?

Comment: @CBroe that would make sense, do you know of any documentation that explains this?

Comment: @CBroe you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can access the `currentSrc` of the `img` element within a `picture` element to get the applied image.

In the demo below (if you're on a desktop with your browser full-width) the `currentSrc` will be the `http://placehold.it/600x100` image.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const picture = document.getElementById('pictureEl');
  const currentSource = document.getElementById('currentSource');
  currentSource.innerText = picture.querySelector('img').currentSrc;
}
```

```html
<picture id="pictureEl">
 <source srcset="http://placehold.it/600x100?text=Source" media="(min-width: 300px)">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Img">
</picture>
<div id="currentSource"></div>
```

Comment: incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get source of image.

```
function getCurrentSrc(element, cb){
    var getSrc;
    if(!window.HTMLPictureElement){
        if(window.respimage){
            respimage({elements: [element]});
        } else if(window.picturefill){
            picturefill({elements: [element]});
        }
        cb(element.src);
        return;
    }

    getSrc = function(){
        element.removeEventListener('load', getSrc);
        element.removeEventListener('error', getSrc);
        cb(element.currentSrc);
    };

    element.addEventListener('load', getSrc);
    element.addEventListener('error', getSrc);
    if(element.complete){
        getSrc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are `window.respimage` and `window.picturefill` coming from?

Comment: They do not exist as native browser methods, but there are 2 libraries with those names.