# Alternative link for <a> tag for webp images?

Tags: lightbox, webp

I use a lightbox image gallery for my website. ([Fslightbox.js](https://fslightbox.com/)) I can use   and  for the thumbnails for webp alternative but when images are clicked for the lightbox i can only use one option such as:

```
<a data-lightbox href="images/image.webp"> 
  <picture>
    <source srcset="images/image-thumbnail.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="images/image-thumbnail.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="images/image-thumbnail.jpg" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
</a>
```

How can i alternate href as "images/image.jpg" so that old browsers that do not support webp could also see the related image?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const pictures = document.querySelectorAll('a > picture');

pictures.forEach(picture => {
  const img = picture.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  img.addEventListener('load', _ =>
    picture.parentNode.setAttribute('href', img.currentSrc)
  );
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" loading="lazy">
  </picture>
</a>
```

You may need to transpile (and/or polyfill) the above JS to support older browsers. However, setting the `href` to the most compatible fallback by default should prevent any noticeable issue on older browsers. Also, wrap that snippet in an event listener for window DOMContentLoaded.

This answer is based on [Get the current image source of a picture element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41762621/11613622).

Comment: I think this will get the src of the "thumbnail" so the image within the link. The idea with lightbox is of course to display a bigger image and not the image that is already displayed.